# Python2 with Beautiful Soup - Filtering on elements with multiple CSS classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get BS4 to filter elements out that contain a certain class.  Here's my HTML:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<table>
    <tr class='test hidden'><td>foo</td></tr>
    <tr class='testabc'><td>bar</td></tr>   
    <tr class='test hidden'><td>foo</td></tr>
    <tr class='testxyz'><td>bar</td></tr>   
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

And my Python code:

```
# import libraries
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment
import operator

with open('sample.html', 'r') as myfile:
    html=myfile.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find('table').find_all('tr', class_=lambda x: 'hidden' not in x)

for row in rows:
    print row
```

You can see that the table has rows with either class='test hidden' or class='full'.  I'm trying to get all the rows where 'hidden' is not a class on the element.

**Essentially I want the output to be:**

```
<tr class='testabc'><td>bar</td></tr>   
<tr class='testxyz'><td>bar</td></tr>
```

**Instead, I get all the rows:**

```
<tr class='test123 hidden'><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr class='testabc'><td>bar</td></tr>   
<tr class='test456 hidden'><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr class='testxyz'><td>bar</td></tr>
```

I've tried multiple combinations of "not in" or "!=".  I've tried creating a function that the lambda calls so I could see what type of object the x is and get a better understanding of how to work with it, but I can't get it to work unless I hard-code the lambda to something like lambda x: x == 'testabc' or x=='testxyz'

Is this possible to do what I'm attempting? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problrem is that the `class_` argument uses only the first string in the `attrs['class']` list.
You can use `.get('class')` to access the full list of classes.

Using a lambda:

```
rows = soup.find('table').find_all(
    lambda tag: tag.name == 'tr' and 'hidden' not in tag.get('class', '')
)
```

Using list comprehensions:

```
rows = [
    tr for tr in soup.find('table').find_all('tr') if 'hidden' not in tr.get('class', '')
]
```

Comment: This works great! I used the lambda in your first example.  It's not "elegant" but I don't think it's that bad.  It's just a little odd that it has to be done this way instead of the other way.  It's pretty close to what I originally had written.  

Thanks! Loving Python thus far, only a few days into it...

Comment: Yeah, python is amazing. I use it for a couple of years now but still lerning new things avery day!

Comment: Agreed.  I just started getting into it, but I see great things in my future in terms of automating and other fun.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this (get ll the tr elements then filter out the ones you don't want):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<table>
    <tr class='test hidden'><td>foo</td></tr>
    <tr class='testabc'><td>bar</td></tr>
    <tr class='test hidden'><td>foo</td></tr>
    <tr class='testxyz'><td>bar</td></tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find('table').find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    if 'hidden' not in row.attrs['class']:
        print row
```

Outputs:

```
<tr class="testabc"><td>bar</td></tr>
<tr class="testxyz"><td>bar</td></tr>
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that'd be the way I'd do it if nothing else worked, but it seemed like something that could be done without the extra work.  Seems like what you're doing in the loop is the same logic as I've tried to apply to the lambda, so it seems something doesn't work quite right when it's applied during the find vs. checking it in the loop.